# How to use keycloak.logout() using the keycloak-installed-adapter in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, keycloak

I'm trying to use Keycloak to secure my desktop application. For starters i'm still trying to use the example just like in the documentation which can be found here https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/securing_apps/index.html#_installed_adapter. I can login just fine, get the tokens and all user data but for some reason whenever i call the method keycloak.logout() it just redirects me to the "login succesful" page and refuses to logout. 
Am i missing something obvious?

I've already tried to redirect the user to the logout page at http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/{My-Realm}/protocol/openid-connect/logout
but that doesnt seem like to do anything. 
The only workaround i found is to change the redirect_uri to /auth/realms/{My-Realm}/account/* and from there just click on sign-out

For the client configuration, i followed the instructions found here https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/installed-adapter.adoc

Here is the keycloak.json

```
{
  "realm": "{My-Realm",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth/",
  "resource": "login",
  "public-client": true,
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true
}
```

And here is the test class

```
KeycloakInstalled keycloak = new KeycloakInstalled();

keycloak.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
keycloak.login();

AccessToken token = keycloak.getToken();

System.out.println("Logged in...");
System.out.println("Token: " + token.getSubject());
System.out.println("Username: " + token.getPreferredUsername());
String username = token.getPreferredUsername();
String userToken = token.getSubject();
Access realmAccess = token.getRealmAccess();
User user = new User();
HashSet < String > roles = (HashSet < String > ) realmAccess.getRoles();
System.out.println("Role: " + roles);
user.setUsername(username);
user.setRole(roles);
user.setToken(userToken);
user.setKeycloak(keycloak);
try {
    System.out.println("AccessToken: " + keycloak.getTokenString());
    user.setAccessToken(keycloak.getTokenString());
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

int timeoutSeconds = 3;
System.out.printf("Logging out in...%d Seconds%n", timeoutSeconds);
try {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(timeoutSeconds);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    keycloak.logout();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Exiting...");
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: I experience the same issue. I have submitted bug report https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-10752

Comment: I have found a bug in Keycloak. See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-10752?focusedCommentId=13754504&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13754504

Comment: Thank you for lettign me know!. So as far as i read from that, its an actual bug from keycloak?

Comment: I think so. Please vote for the bug report.